# Setting a div height in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have three `div`s with the same class name that I want to alter the height and color of using JavaScript. My code is breaking, not sure why. I've looked at answers to similar problems on here and my code seems to be the same as the solutions.

Any idea on where my code is breaking and how to fix it ?

```
<HTML>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <div class="bar"></div>
    <script>
        function altSize() {
            var bar = document.getElementsByClassName("bar");
            bar.style.height = 200px;
            bar.style.background = 'red';
        }
        altSize();
    </script>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Comment: `.bar{height: 200px;}` why not this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's breaking here:

```
      bar.style.height=200px;
```

The reason is that `200px` is not something you can assign in JS, it reads the 200 and doesn't know what to do with the px, it's not a valid number.

Moreover, [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName) returns a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList) and not a single element.

Fix it with

```
      for(var i=0;i<bar.length;i++){
           bar[i].style.height="200px";
      }
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/afZb3/)

Comment: I think you mean `getElementsByClassName` :)

Comment: Do I need to create an array to put the div element classes in?

Comment: @moonshineOutlaw no, you don't. When you perform a getElementsByClassName query it returns a NodeList (Not exactly an array but can be iterated just the same). Below the last code sample in my answer I have a fiddle - you might want to check that out.